# Smarty for greeting not functioning anymore on civicrm > 5.35

Tags: smarty

Is there any reason why a custom greeting using smarty wouldn't work anymore on recent versions of CiviCRM:

`{if "{contact.gender}"=="Femme"}Chère{ }{contact.first_name}{elseif "{contact.gender}"=="Homme"}Cher{ }{contact.first_name}{/if}`

was working smoothly until recently on both WP and Drupal?

I don't understand what happened :-/

Of course Smarty is enabled :

```
if (!defined('CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY')) {   define( 'CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY', 1 ); }
```

Comment: I just tested it and it still works for us on 5.35.2 Drupal 7.x. Did you maybe change the values for {contact.gender}? Maybe you also want to  include an else option such as this: {if "{contact.gender}"=="Femme"}Chère{ }{contact.first_name}{elseif "{contact.gender}"=="Homme"}Cher{ }{contact.first_name}{else}Hi there{/if}

Comment: thanks Fabian, I'll try this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gender wasn't properly define and @Fabian inspired me this little improvement:

`{if "{contact.gender}"=="Femme"}Chère{ }{contact.first_name}{elseif "{contact.gender}"=="Homme"}Cher{ }{contact.first_name}{else}{contact.first_name}{/if}`